# How can I determine what individual ulimit constraint a process has?

Tags: linux, process, ulimit

I have a service that sets a custom limit for open files (`ulimit -n 5000`) as part of its init script.  My understanding is that this will be effectively for the service and its child processes.  Since I'm **not** configuring `/etc/security/limits.conf` I think it's normal for me to see a different value when typing `ulimit -a`.

So my question is: how can I confirm what individual open file limit a given process has? Is this something that `ps` would show?

Comment: I think it can be determined from `proc/pid/limits`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `/proc/pid/limits` is the file you should check. For example, I have the below entry for one process in my system.

```
Max open files            50                   50                   files
```